# Error Message : go: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory;

Tags: go

I am trying to run a unit test using go. The functions work properly in the main file. The function is given below:

```golang
func LoadLexicon(lexiconPath string) (map[string]string, error) {
    m := make(map[string]string)
    lexiconPath = strings.TrimSuffix(lexiconPath, "\n")
    if lexiconPath == "nil" {
        m["COME"] = "k V m"
        m["WORDS"] = "w 3` d z"
        m["MECCA"] = "m E k @"

        return m, nil
    }
    readFile, err := os.Open(lexiconPath)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return m, err
    }

    fileScanner := bufio.NewScanner(readFile)
    fileScanner.Split(bufio.ScanLines)
    var fileLines []string

    for fileScanner.Scan() {
        fileLines = append(fileLines, fileScanner.Text())
    }

    lex_words := make(map[string]string)

    for _, line := range fileLines {
        temp := strings.Split(line, "\t")
        lex_words[strings.ToUpper(temp[0])] = temp[1]
    }

    return lex_words, err

}
```

But when I am running the unit test,

```golang
func TestLoadLexicon(t *testing.T) {
    tests := []struct {
        n    string
        want string
    }{
        {"COME", "k V m"},
        {"WORDS", "w 3` d z"},
        {"MECCA", "m E k @"},
    }
    for _, tc := range tests {
        if got, _ := LoadLexicon("nil"); got[tc.n] != tc.want {
            t.Errorf("got %s, want %s", got[tc.n], tc.want)
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting this error
`
Running tool: /usr/local/go/bin/go test -timeout 30s -run ^TestLoadLexicon$

go: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory; see 'go help modules'

> Test run finished at 29/08/2022, 02:58:53 <
> `

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a [go.mod](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-go-modules#understanding-the-go-mod-file) file to your project's root directory.

Use modules to manage dependencies. Official docs: https://go.dev/blog/using-go-modules

Example:

```
go mod init project-name


go mod init example.com/project-name


go mod init github.com/you-user-name/project-name
```

You may need to use the tidy command to clean up after running one of the above commands.

```
go mod tidy
```

Use the path format from above when importing a package into your go file

Example:

```
import (
   // Import internal and external packages like this
   "github.com/you-user-name/project-name/package-name"

   // Import standard library packages the normal way
   "testing"
   "math/rand"
)
```

Comment: still same error I am getting

Answer (score -1):

it can be error workspace problem，you can disable workspace use:
'''
go env -w GOWORK=""
'''